# Best alternative to MATLAB's global variables

Tags: performance, matlab, global-variables

I'm writing a [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) application which has many functions spread over different files. I have a logger, which is a struct with a function pointer, and I use it to log information for the user to see (that is, which function is currently executing, calculation results, etc.). The reason I use a struct for my logger and not simply `fprintf()` is that I could easily replace it with an XML logger, HTML logger, etc. in the future.

Since my code is composed of many functions calling each other, I declared my logger struct as global, so I don't have to pass it to all my many functions. However, everywhere I look I see that global variables are evil incarnate in MATLAB and will slow my program down considerably.

Is there a way to have variables available across files without necessarily passing them as input parameters, and without suffering from severe performance penalty?

Comment: Global vars are not "evil". They just can create many errors if you're not an experienced programmer, such as overloading other vars etc. Also, i don't believe there is a performance hit for globals in Matlab. If using globals makes your life "extremely" easier, then use them. Just try not to make it a habit.

Comment: @Jorge any programmer, not just the inexperienced ones. But otherwise, yeah.

Comment: @Jorge - what is your criteria for using globals vs. passing variables to methods?

Comment: You could have a look at using [application data](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f13-998352.html#f13-999565). I have only ever used this when making GUIs, but it may be useful in other contexts too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use **persistent** keyword inside a file, and allocate the logger there.
It is similar in some ways to the **static** keyword in C++.  It is also an implementation of the ***Singleton*** pattern.

```
function CallLogger(st)
    persistent logger;
    if isempty(logger)
        %Allocate new logger
    end
    logger.disp(st);
end
```

It is better than global because
 1. No one can destroy your logger without your knowledge.
 2. No one even knows about this object, because it is limited to the function scope

By the way, I don't agree that global has a performance issue. It is just not a good practice, in terms of Software Engineering.

Comment: Hi @Andrey,The way I see it, persistent variables are the equivalent of "static" variables in C/C++ so they only exist inside the function scope and not across functions, right?

Comment: Thanks Andrey, your answer is great. I decided to move away from globals as much as I can, for both good practice and performance. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Better than invoking persistent variables in a function (which, for example, won't be saved if you save and then reload your workspace) would be to move from function + struct to object: that is, you should look into MATLAB's object oriented programming.

Comment: Are you referring to creating a new class that inherits the MATLAB handle class?